# angular 6 or 7: How to import RequestOptions and ResponseContentType in '@angular/common/http'

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have migrated angular 4 code to angular 6 and I want to know how to import below code in angular 6 or 7?

```
import { RequestOptions, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Pass this way ...

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

 let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 });
 let options = {
    headers: headers
 }

 this.http.post(URL, param, options)
    .subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
 });



 // For pass blob in API 

 return this.http.get(url, { headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Authorization': '{data}',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 }), responseType: 'blob'}).pipe (
 tap (
     // Log the result or error
     data => console.log('You received data'),
     error => console.log(error)
  )
);
```

Comment: I want to use ResponseContentType.Blob

Comment: @AmolBLande I have update my answer please check  that.

Comment: @AmolBLande Can you please update your status on this issue ?

Comment: @AmolBLande Welcome. Happy to help you.

Comment: No typings here? Coming from a typed object now to a loosly nameless in-the-parameter-defined type. Not awesome from Angular.