# Angular 7 get method append rest API BASE URL into app URL

Tags: rest, angular7, angular-httpclient

Hi I'm new to Angular I ma trying to make a get call(`localhost:8080/optq/api/test/roles`) using Angular method but it is appending my host app URL to REST API URL like this.
what part i am missing?

```
http://localhost:4200/localhost:8080/optq/api/test/roles 404 (Not Found)
```

code

```
getRoles(){
    this.http.get(this.rolesUrl)
    .subscribe((payload: Payload<Role>) => {
        this.roleList = payload.result.map((response: Role) => {
          return <Role>{
            id: response.id,
            name: response.name
          };
        });
      });
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `this.rolesUrl`? seems to me you are setting it to "localhost..."  or "/localhost..." hence "http://localhost:4200/" origin is prefixed.

Comment: also since you are using `angular7` with updated RxJS, you might want to take advantage of it, and move you `payload.result.map` like `this.http.get(this.rolesUrl).pipe(map(payload: Payload<Role>)=>{...}).subscribe(...`

Comment: private rolesUrl="http:localhost:8080/optq/api/test/roles";

Comment: hi @j4rey so it will be going to solve my problem

Comment: it should be `http://localhost:4200/optq/api/test/roles`

Comment: yes thank but now CORS

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/optq/api/test/roles' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: you have angular running on http://localhost:4200 and API running on http://localhost:8080 right? then it should be actually be `http://localhost:8080/optq/api/test/roles`.
 for CORS you have to configure your API to allow Cross Origin Request.

Comment: yes and how to add cors policy in my case

Comment: simply put you have to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header.  Read up on it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. anyway that's a separate question, not related your current question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118316/angular-6-or-7-how-to-import-requestoptions-and-responsecontenttype-in-angula

Answer (score 0):

Try using following get method

```
get(url: string): Promise<any> {
            return this.http
                .get(url, { headers: this.headers })
                .toPromise()
                .then(res => {
                    return res.json() as any;
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }
```