# Tyring to import import { HttpClient, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/common/http';

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Im working with ionic 4 project. and now im trying to make an http post and im follwoing the tut on this link: https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-http-post/. now it is saying that he cant find Headers, RequestOptions in @angular/common/http';

I tried different thing i find on stack overflow.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, Headers, RequestOptions } from 
'@angular/common/http';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
 }
 ngOnInit(){}

  sendPostRequest() {
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

let postData = {
        "name": "Customer004",
        "email": "customer004@email.com",
        "tel": "0000252525"
}

this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/customers", postData, requestOptions)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data['_body']);
   }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }
```

Comment: The issue come from your version of angular. `Headers` has been renamed as `HttpHeaders` in Angular 6+. [@angular/common/http documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http). Which version of Angular are you using ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations

Answer (score 2):

Hi try this insted of headers use HttpHeaders:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders , RequestOptions } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular 5 Onward, If you want to communicate in `JSON` only then it is not required to set `Content-Type` as `application/json`. It will default communicate in `JSON` format.

So you can just use it as

**For GET call**

```
this.http.get('YOUR API').subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**For POST call**

```
this.http.post('YOUR API', `{JSON OBJECT}`).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**You can also add Custom Headers for example Authorization token as below**

`import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

`requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Token')`;

and use it as below

**For GET call**

```
this.http.get('YOUR API', {headers: this.requestHeaders}).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**For POST call**

```
this.http.post('YOUR API', `{JSON OBJECT}`, {headers: this.requestHeaders}).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

`HttpHeaders` includes the methods like `set()`, `append()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

this is how we can add header

```
  import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


    let yourheaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    let youroptions = {
    headers: yourheaders
    }
```

Take look [this](https://angular.io/guide/http)
look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19044) [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118316/angular-6-or-7-how-to-import-requestoptions-and-responsecontenttype-in-angula)

Comment: Hii the header part is fixed now thanks. But i still get the error that RequestOptions is not find in @angular/common/http?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it Simple:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
}
```

Get Api:

```
this.http.get('https://someapi.com/posts').subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Post Api:

```
    let YourHeaders = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};
    this.http.post(url, YourData, {headers: YourHeaders})
      .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    },
    (error) => {
            console.log("Error" + error)
    })
```