# append header not added in header for api basic auth in ionic

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, post

Hi I'm new to ionic and angular a lot of things I still didn't know, i want to send post requests to API with basic auth. here's my code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {
    this.call();
  }

call(){
var data = {username:"someusername",password:"somepassword"}
let body = JSON.stringify(data);

let header= new HttpHeaders({
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Method': 'POST',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization':'Basic ZHJlYW1fMS4wOmRyZWFtXzEuMA==',
});

let options = {headers: header}

this.http.post("someUrl", body, options).subscribe(data =>{
  console.log(data)
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});

}
}
```

I'm following a tutorial from [this link](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-http-post/) but looks like I'm using the new version ionic, so I changed a bit by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118316/angular-6-or-7-how-to-import-requestoptions-and-responsecontenttype-in-angula). but I get an error like this.

[image: image error from console log]

then I realized, looks like my headers not added to the URL.

[image: image from console.log(options)]

and here's an image from console.log(error)

[image: image from console.log(error)]

so my question is, how to append header to the URL? if the header is added to the URL will this solve the problem? or maybe I am missing something?

thank you in advance, and sorry for bad grammar English.

Comment: let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Authorization', :Basic ZHJlYW1fMS4wOmRyZWFtXzEuMA==');

this.http.post("someUrl", body,, { headers: headers })

Comment: Hi @RaviAshara thank you for your answare, i have tried your answare, but i still get the same problem, maybe you can explain it ? thankyou.

Comment: Just send me network call

Comment: @RaviAshara thanks for the invitation, but can you just explain it in the comment?

Comment: in browser press F12 and call login api and check in network "header" call

Answer (score 0):

Here I have provided a sample code for adding headers for your reference:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {
    this.call();
  }

call(){
var data = {username:"someusername",password:"somepassword"}
let body = JSON.stringify(data);
const requestHeader = new HttpHeaders()
.set('Authorization', 'Basic ZHJlYW1fMS4wOmRyZWFtXzEuMA==')
let options = {headers: requestheader}

this.http.post("someUrl", body, options).subscribe(data =>{
  console.log(data)
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});

}
}
```

Comment: Hi @pooja, thanks for answare, but i still get same error like above. i wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

I change my library to the new one in ionic 6 documentation ([link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http#usage))

```
import { HTTP } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/http/ngx';

constructor(private http: HTTP) {}

...

this.http.get('http://ionic.io', {}, {})
  .then(data => {

    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);

  })
  .catch(error => {

    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);

});
```